# Selenium waits for page to load after click?

Tags: python, selenium

Im pretty sure my code is not needed for this. Anyways, when i use the click function in python with selenium, it waits for the next page to load before quitting, which is not what i want. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: You can decrease the page load timeout if you don't want to wait, e.g. `driver.set_page_load_timeout(3)`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.